# Arima for time series in minute

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, arima

I am a beginner in machine learning for time series, I need to develop a project, where my data is composed of minutes, could someone help me create this algorithm?

**Data set:** Each value represents one minute of collection (9:00, 9:01 ...), the collection lasts 10 minutes and was performed in 2 months, that is, 10 values ​​for January and 10 values for the month of February.

[image]

[Complete data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b0a130847a96ea57da6dc189295b6f79/minute.csv)

**Objective:** I would like my result to be a forecast of the next 10 minutes for month of March, example:

```
2020-03-01 9:00:00
2020-03-01 9:01:00
2020-03-01 9:02:00
2020-03-01 9:03:00
```

**Training:** The training must contain the month of January and February as a reference for forecasting, taking into account that it is a time series

**Seasonal:**

[image]

**Forecast:**

> **Current problem:** it seems that the current forecast is failing, the
>   previous data does not seem to be valid as a time series, because, as
>   can be seen in the seasonality image, the data set is shown as a
>   straight line. The forecast is represented by the green line in the
>   figure below, and the original data by the blue line, however as we
>   see the date axis is going until 2020-11-01, it should go until
>   2020-03-01, in addition the original data form a rectangle in the
>   graph

[image]

**script.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pmdarima as pm
    #%matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
    from dateutil.parser import parse
except ImportError as e:
    print("[FAILED] {}".format(e))

class operationsArima():

    @staticmethod
    def ForecastingWithArima():

        try:

            # Import
            data = pd.read_csv('minute.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')

            # Plot
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10,5), dpi=100, sharex=True)

            # Usual Differencing
            axes[0].plot(data[:], label='Original Series')
            axes[0].plot(data[:].diff(1), label='Usual Differencing')
            axes[0].set_title('Usual Differencing')
            axes[0].legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)
            print("[OK] Generated axes")

            # Seasonal
            axes[1].plot(data[:], label='Original Series')
            axes[1].plot(data[:].diff(11), label='Seasonal Differencing', color='green')
            axes[1].set_title('Seasonal Differencing')
            plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)
            plt.suptitle('Drug Sales', fontsize=16)
            plt.show()

            # Seasonal - fit stepwise auto-ARIMA
            smodel = pm.auto_arima(data, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                                    test='adf',
                                    max_p=3, max_q=3, m=11,
                                    start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                                    d=None, D=1, trace=True,
                                    error_action='ignore',
                                    suppress_warnings=True,
                                    stepwise=True)

            smodel.summary()
            print(smodel.summary())
            print("[OK] Generated model")

            # Forecast
            n_periods = 11
            fitted, confint = smodel.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
            index_of_fc = pd.date_range(data.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS')

            # make series for plotting purpose
            fitted_series = pd.Series(fitted, index=index_of_fc)
            lower_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 0], index=index_of_fc)
            upper_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 1], index=index_of_fc)
            print("[OK] Generated series")

            # Plot
            plt.plot(data)
            plt.plot(fitted_series, color='darkgreen')
            plt.fill_between(lower_series.index,
                            lower_series,
                            upper_series,
                            color='k', alpha=.15)

            plt.title("ARIMA - Final Forecast - Drug Sales")
            plt.show()
            print("[SUCESS] Generated forecast")

        except Exception as e:

            print("[FAILED] Caused by: {}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flow = operationsArima()
    flow.ForecastingWithArima() # Init script
```

**Sumary:**

```
                                SARIMAX Results                                 
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                        y   No. Observations:                   22
Model:             SARIMAX(0, 1, 0, 11)   Log Likelihood                     nan
Date:                  Mon, 13 Apr 2020   AIC                                nan
Time:                          21:19:10   BIC                                nan
Sample:                               0   HQIC                               nan
                                   - 22                                         
Covariance Type:                    opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intercept           0   5.33e-13          0      1.000   -1.05e-12    1.05e-12
sigma2          1e-10   5.81e-10      0.172      0.863   -1.04e-09    1.24e-09
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (Q):                         nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                  nan
Prob(Q):                               nan   Prob(JB):                          nan
Heteroskedasticity (H):                nan   Skew:                              nan
Prob(H) (two-sided):                   nan   Kurtosis:                          nan
===================================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 22 values suggest two diametrically opposed viewpoints/approaches.
You have 11 values per cyscle.

The first approach is to detect latent deterministic structure (i.e. unspecified causals ) ... in this case 7 of the 11 time points are statistically significant .

7 seasonal dummies reflecting 7 of the 11 periods were statistically significant [image] . The augmented data set is here  [image] . The Actual/Fit and Forecast graph is here [image] .  This approach identifies and augments the observed data with 10 dummies and finds three of them to be not-significant.

An alternate approach id to use the pure rear-window approach (arima) which simply believes that the past should be the basis for the forecast ignoring the fact that the past never causes the future and is only a proxy for omitted causal variables.

Using this approach the "found model" is here [image] where the value 11 periods is the best estimate of a future value.

Since the observed series is DETERMINISTIC , the resulting forecasts (BUT NOT INTERPRETATION) are identical.

My rational mind leaning on "causes" rather than simple memory strongly suggests that in this case approach 1 is not only the better strategy but it is sufficient , if not parsimonious.

My seasoned/general approach to time series modelling encompasses studying both approaches and seamlessly integrating both kinds of components when necessary along with any user-specified causal series.

I hope that this brings some clarity to your question although I couldn't exactly answer or duplicate you results.

Comment: your approach is as didactic as that of a teacher, excellent, congratulations, for sure every point of view of someone experienced can help, could you make available the code you used, tools and the like to perform such tests?

Comment: The "code" is AUTOBOX , available in R ,  however for the first approach simply create 10 seasonal dummies ..perform a regression ,, step-down and then you get my results.  The second approach requires sophisticated arima model identification strategies ala https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf . Please accept my answer if you are as pleased as you say you are.

Comment: ok, very good, thanks a lot!